# Quelle est la différence sémantique entre l'origine et la cause ?

Tags: sens

Je suis en train de lire [la quatrième de couverture d'un livre](https://www.fayard.fr/la-revanche-des-passions-9782213655079) et je ne comprends pas la différence entre les mots *l'origine* et *la cause* dans le contexte suivant :

> *À l’heure où la mondialisation met en question la cohérence de l’État national, où les armes, notamment atomiques, changent la nature de la guerre, les conflits interétatiques cèdent le pas aux guerres civiles, au terrorisme et à la montée de la violence sociale. **Ce déchaînement des passions est-il à l’origine des bouleversements actuels, ou en sont-ils la cause ?***

On ne sait pas très bien quels sont *les bouleversements* mais pour moi l'origine est ici comprise comme *Point de départ ; première cause.* [tel que l'a défini Wikitionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/origine). Je ne vois pas la différence avec *la cause* dans la phrase du coup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clef du problème réside dans le mot **en**. On peut aussi détecter le retournement des deux éléments dans la seconde partie de la phrase grâce au genre et nombre du pronom utilisé, **ils**. Ce dernier ne représente clairement pas le déchaînement *(singulier)*, ni les passions *(féminines)*, et doit donc désigner les bouleversement actuels.

La seconde partie de la phrase doit se comprendre ainsi :

> Les bouleversements actuels sont-ils la cause de ce déchaînement des passions ?

...ou, davantage dans l’esprit de la phrase originale :

> [...] ou ces derniers en sont-ils la cause ?

Ceci dit, la tournure utilisée ne brille ni par sa clarté, ni par son élégance.

Comment: +1 et oui pour l'observation finale d'une gaucherie certaine. Après... c'est une 4è de couverture. C'est un challenge ça une 4è de couverture. On s'imagine pas ou alors... quand on s'imagine... on ne les lit plus... ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt La quatrième de couverture, c'est peut-être un challenge, mais quand elle est bien faite, elle vaut certainement une petite fortune aux éditeurs :~) Libre à eux de les bâcler, bien sûr, mais si c'était moi...

Answer (score 0):

Pour moi, l'origine et la cause signifient d'abord l'existence d'une historicité, plus précisément d'une antécédence, dans la relation entre les deux événeemnts mis en relation : l'un s'est produit, ou a produit l'essentiel de ses effets, avant l'autre, et la survenue de cette autre est liée aux effets de son antécédent. Mais il reste une différence sémantique en ce qui concerne, disons le pouvoir d'explication.

Exemple simpliste : un jour, ma mère, Adèle, a croisé un ami, Bernard, qui lui a présenté mon père, Charles ; Bernard est à l'origine de… ben, moi. Mais c'est plutôt la rencontre devenue amoureuse d'Adèle et Charles qui est "ma" cause.

Si l'événement A est à l'origine de l'événement B, cela signifie que ce B s'est produit à la suite de A ; cela ne dit pas que B ne se serait pas produit si A n'était pas produit. Alors qu'en affirmant que A est la cause de B, je signifie que, dès que A s'est produit, il devient inéluctable que B, ou quelque chose comme B, se produise aussi. Je note qu'en écrivant "inéluctable", je force la relation de A sur B à devenir prédictible. Il ne s'agit pas de ne dire ic que des « lois de la Nature », comme en physique déterministe. Dans le premier exemple ci-dessus, j'aurais bien pu naître… un·e autre, par ex. d'un autre sexe. Le jeu de la relation origine vs. cause est donc bien sûr à chercher au niveau de l'explication a posteriori. Et ce sera ensuite la volonté de quelqu'un, de faire de cet exemple, une généralité, qui pourra être source de débat. Le côté originel d'une antécédence est rarement discutable, la causalité du premier événenement sur le second l'est pratiquement toujours.

Par exemple, l'extinction des dinosaures est à l'origine de la radiation des mammifères, et incidemment celle de l'être humain, mais je ne crois pas que l'on puisse défendre que l'impact de l'astéroïde de Chicxulub soit la, ou même des causes, du réchauffement climatique actuel :-), contrairement à la découverte et mise au point de la machine à vapeur... J'énonce ceci comme causale, c'est-à-dire explicatrice, parce que je n'imagine pas que : le contexte de progression de l'humanité (jolie mais horrible globalisation…) ces derniers siècles aurait pu se produire sans le déclic de cette invention technique à l'origine de l'industrialisation de notre société d'une part ; que d'une autre part, tant que cette humanité n'aurait pas "fait le tour de la question des facilités apportées par ce progrès technique", pourquoi s'arrêterait-elle ? ; et enfin que c'est ce "souci", le dérèglement du climat , au sens de la perte de notre zone de "confort", qui deviendrait le facteur limitant de cette déraisonnable expansion. Pour ce dernier point, puisque ce ne fut ni la fin des ressources énergétiques (fossiles : qui se soucie du futur "second" choc pétrolier, celui de la fin définitive de cette gaspillable ressource), ni la raréfaction de certaines matières premières (d'aucuns pensent les trouver dans d'imaginaires astéroïdes "minables"…). La « tendance du moment » est bien, pour une fraction "importante" de l'humanité, de considérer que notre première urgence est de traiter ce phénomène de réchauffement climatique, devenu « faute de réelles contestations », événement, et dont il ne fait plus doute, sinon pour quelques esprits retors, qu'il est de *cause* dite "anthropique", ce synonyme moins culpabilisant que "humaine"…

De façon adjacente, il me semble que, le plus souvent, on parle deS causeS, mettons A1, A2,... An (pour faire comme les matheux), d'un événement B. Pour moi, si cette description est exhaustive et non-redondante (pas d'événement Aj dont un Ai soitla/une cause…), cela sous-entend bien que si un seul de ces événements A1, A2… An ne s'était pas produit, alors B ne se serait pas produit.